# Mercedes-Benz battery charge warning light

Tags: battery, alternator, mercedes-benz, e320

I have a Mercedes-Benz model 2004 with V-6 petrol engine E320.

On the dash-board a battery mark you can watch always unless you push the botton on steering wheel will disappear. And battery still ok , this now since about 70 days.

Please advice me back what exactly I do repair for Bosh alternator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know it is the alternator?

You could buy a new one, fit it and still have the same problem.

You need to test the alternator and electrical system to isolate the fault - it could be internal to the alternator or it could be a broken wire between the alternator and battery or ignition controlled supply.

If this has been going on for 70 days, then it may be a diode in the alternator or even a short on the warning light wire putting the warning light on but not affecting the charging of the battery.

Needs testing.